# C++: is it possible to search a vector/container for a particular string/value and return its index?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I would appreciate some advice related to manipulating data in vectors.

I have written code that results in two sets of vectors: strings (labels/names) and doubles (data).  The order of the labels in the string vector may be different for each calculation I do.

Here's what I would like to do.  Let's say that one element (label) in the vector is: Tom.  I would like to know if it is possible to search the string/label vector for "Tom" and return the index of Tom's location in the vector.

Is this something that sounds possible in C++?  I would appreciate any tips.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `std::find`

```
vector<string>::iterator it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "Tom");
if (it == vec.end()) 
    return -1;
else
    return it - vec.begin();
```

A better solution would be to pick a more suitable container, such as the mentioned `std::map`

Comment: Thank you Erik.  I didn't know about find.

Comment: what about using `std::distance(vec.begin(), it)`?

Comment: @bruce.banner `std::distance` is only useful when you want support for non-random access iterators. Given that this code works solely with `std::vector`, which has random access iterators, this abstraction would add no value here.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `std::map` for that.

Comment: The order of the labels in the vector apparently matters so a `map` may not work.

Comment: We can set comparison class to preserve order.

Answer (score 1):

As vissi says - you really want an associative array

If you have to use vectors you can sort the vector and then use one of the std::find  functions to return an iterator ie a pointer to the position.

ps. You say you have two vectors? Presumably you want to keep them in order, which means sorting just the strings would be bad. You probably want a container class that has a string and value - a vector of which can be sorted